# Nginx Buffer Manipulation when Sending Request

Tags: c, nginx

I am learning Nginx module development from a [hello world case](https://tejgop.github.io/nginx-module-guide/). I am wondering why we don't need `ngx_memcpy` here to copy the `ngx_hello_world` into the `ngx_buf_t`. I was told that Nginx is all asynchronous. Will the return of function stack invalidate the memory that the buffer's pos and last points to?

```c
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_hello_world_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r)
{
  u_char *ngx_hello_world = (u_char *) "Hello World!";
  size_t sz = strlen(ngx_hello_world);

  r->headers_out.content_type.len = strlen("text/html") - 1;
  r->headers_out.content_type.data = (u_char *) "text/html";
  r->headers_out.status = NGX_HTTP_OK;
  r->headers_out.content_length_n = sz;
  ngx_http_send_header(r);

  ngx_buf_t    *b;
  ngx_chain_t   *out;

  b = ngx_calloc_buf(r->pool);

  out = ngx_alloc_chain_link(r->pool);

  out->buf = b;
  out->next = NULL;

  b->pos = ngx_hello_world;
  b->last = ngx_hello_world + sz;
  b->memory = 1;
  b->last_buf = 1;

  return ngx_http_output_filter(r, out);
}
```